# Swift 4: Cannot assign value of type '[X]' to type '[VC.X]'

Tags: ios, json, swift

How can I eliminate this compiler error? If I declare items inside the function, all works.

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    struct X: Decodable  {
        let id: String
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }
    var items = [X]()

    //-----------------------------

    func somefunc()  {
        do {
            // the error is here:
            self.items = try JSONDecoder().decode([X].self, from: data)    <<<<<<<<<<< Compile error is here
        }
        catch  let err  {
        }
    }
}         // class VC
```

Comment: the code works for me without an error.. do you happen to have some other struct with na `X` in the code? try using `self.items = try JSONDecoder().decode([VC.X].self, from: Data())` instead

Comment: Cannot reproduce, even not with another "outside" `struct X`

Comment: Is your function somefunc() inside the VC Class? If yes, this doesn't make sense and you are probably missing some bracket or so... if not you should pass [VC.X].self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be working (I tried it and there was no compiler error), but still, maybe you have already some other class/struct with the same name. Try using this instead just to be sure:

```
self.items = try JSONDecoder().decode([VC.X].self, from: data)
```

Comment: Yes! Adding VC.X got rid of the compiler error. I then realized that the error was probably because this code is in a async task. I neglected to show that. Sorry.